# Javascript merge rows with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to merge rows with specific conditions like so:

- If rows have the same values in col: 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 AND col 3 equals specific value (e.g. 17007) -> merge and the merged row has the sum of col 2.
- Else, do not merge.

I've tried this:

```js
const expect = require('chai').expect

// this function takes an object, check values of all compared columns (a, b, c, d, e) of each row, if there's a match, return a merged row with value col (v) = sum of each old row v
const mergeRows = (obj, v, ...params) => {
    const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const key = params.map(p => {return `${cur[p]}`}).join('|')
        // if the key values don't match
        if (acc[3] === '17007') {
            if(!acc[key]) acc[key] = cur
            // if the key values match
            else acc[key][v] = (+acc[key][v] + +cur[v]).toString()
        }
        else acc[key] = cur;
        return acc
    }, {})

    return Object.values(result)
}

const mergeRowsObj = [
    ['5400-030', '15051', '-77.25', '17001P', 'ARED', 'ABC'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '230.14', '17001P', 'BGRE', 'DEF'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '-145.5', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '103', '17007', 'DYEL', 'IJK'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '-23.4', '17007', 'DYEL', 'IJK'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '203.5', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '10', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '5', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '125', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI']
]
const mergeRowsResultObj = [
    ['5400-030', '15051', '-77.25', '17001P', 'ARED', 'ABC'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '230.14', '17001P', 'BGRE', 'DEF'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '183', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '79.6', '17007', 'DYEL', 'IJK'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '10', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '5', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI']
]

const mergeRowsResult = mergeRows(mergeRowsObj, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5)

console.log(mergeRowsResult);

describe('mergeRows', () => {
    it('should return an object with merged rows that contain the same values of specific columns', () => {
        expect(mergeRowsResult).to.deep.equal(mergeRowsResultObj)
    })
})
```

I've also tried modifying the `reduce()` function to add conditions for the row 3 value like:

```js
if(!acc[key] || cur[3] !== '17007') acc[key] = cur
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `cur` instead of `acc`

```
if (cur[3] === '17007') {
//  ^^^
```

and another unique key for the unchanged rows, in this case I took the  complete row as string as key.

```
acc[Object.values(cur).join('|')] = cur;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
const mergeRows = (obj, v, ...params) => {
    const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const key = params.map(p => cur[p]).join('|')
        if (cur[3] === '17007') {
            if(!acc[key]) acc[key] = cur
            else acc[key][v] = (+acc[key][v] + +cur[v]).toString()
        } else {
            acc[Object.values(cur).join('|')] = cur;
        }
        return acc
    }, {})

    return Object.values(result)
}

const mergeRowsObj = [
    ['5400-030', '15051', '-77.25', '17001P', 'ARED', 'ABC'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '230.14', '17001P', 'BGRE', 'DEF'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '-145.5', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '103', '17007', 'DYEL', 'IJK'],
    ['1250-100', '15051', '-23.4', '17007', 'DYEL', 'IJK'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '203.5', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '10', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-032', '15051', '5', '17008', 'CBLU', 'GHI'],
    ['5400-030', '15051', '125', '17007', 'CBLU', 'GHI']
]

const mergeRowsResult = mergeRows(mergeRowsObj, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5)

mergeRowsResult.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina, you saved me again!